# Qt 5 ODBC driver issue

Tags: qt, odbc, qt5

I am trying to use ODBC driver in one of my Qt5 project.

I compiled `QODBC` driver and copied the driver dlls to the Qt\Qt5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\plugins\sqldrivers folder.

When I try the following code:

```
 QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC");
```

I get the following error:

```
QSqlDatabase: QODBC driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QODBC QODBC3
```

Same error is encountered if I tried loading `QODBC3`.

Even though `QODBC` and `QODBC3` drivers are present, Qt still could not load `QODBC` driver.

I am running Windows 7 (64 bit) PC.

Has anybody encountered such error? Any clues on what might be wrong ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the issue was caused due to incorrect Visual studio versions used while compiling odbc sql driver.

I had both VS 2008 and VS 2010 in my computer. My Qt5.0 was using VS2010. But when I compiled the odbc sql driver, I had used VS2008. And that caused the problem.

Qt was able to detect the sql odbc driver but could not load it.

I solved this by recompiling the odbc driver using VS2010 and odbc driver works pefectly.

**Here are the steps to compile and use sql odbc drivers in Qt 5.0**

1. open qt command prompt:
2. this can be found in start menu under Qt
3. set vc++ environment variables:

   - To do this , cd into to the C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\ folder and run vcvarsall.bat
     *Important point to note is, compile the driver using the same version of Visual Studio thats used by Qt.*
4. cd into \Qt5.0.0\5.0.0\Src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers\odbc source folder
5. `qmake odbc.pro`
6. `nmake`

   - If it runs correctly, the  compiled qsqlodbc.dll and qsqlodbcd.dll
     will be available in \Qt5.0.0\5.0.0\Src\qtbase\plugins\sqldrivers folder.
7. While deploying qt based application, qsqlodbc.dll (release version) need to be copied to sqldrivers folder.