# Qt5 ODBC install

Tags: odbc, qmake, qt5

I'm trying to install QODBC to use it in Qt

I was following the answer of this question : [Qt 5 ODBC driver issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14207088/qt-5-odbc-driver-issue)

but when I "qmaked" it, I run into an error :

```
C:/Qt/Qt5.0.0/5.0.0/Src/qtbase/mkspecs/features/qt_functions.prf:183: resolve_depends(var, prefix) requires one or two arguments.
```

This error is repeated 5 times.

I looked a little over the net, but find nothing concerning it

Comment: Have you tried with Qt 5.0.2? 5.0.0 had several other issues...

Comment: just tried it with Qt 5.0.2. And it works perfectly. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works perfectly with Qt 5.0.2